# Replace URL pattern with 4 numbers after word

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to replace:

```
domain.com/e-books/1234-etc
```

By:

```
domain.com/artigos/1234-etc
```

I'm trying:

```
RewriteRule ^e-books(\d{4}-.*)$ /artigos/(\d{4}-.*)$1 [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT: And this:**

```
RewriteRule ^e-books(\d{4}-.*) /artigos/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: In he replacement, you can only use `$1` to backreference the capture group value in the pattern on the left. You can't use `(\d{4}-.*)` in the replacement. Try `e-books/(\d{4}-.*)` pattern and `/artigos/$1` replacement

Comment: Like this? RewriteRule ^e-books(\d{4}-.*)$ /artigos/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Your edited rule should work

Comment: Great it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^e-books/(.+)$ /artigos/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

Clear your browser'cache before testing this.